# Convert Decimal to Hours in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using excel to sum up all the hours that my team worked on. However, the hours are displayed as 31.60 or 31.70

I want to convert 31.60 = 32 or 31.70 = 32.10. Just need the numbers, no formatting text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the decimal part like `A1-INT(A1)` where `A1` is your data and divide it by 0.6. The integer result that you get is added to the integer part of your cell. And finally add the rest of the division. I didn't manage to keep it short.

`=INT(A1)+ INT((A1-INT(A1))/0.6)+ MOD((A1-INT(A1)),0.6)`

Comment: Tried for below values and it didn't work:
5.30, 4.0, 27.30, 0.30, 2.30. It should sum as 40 hours, but it's displaying 39.20

Comment: btw, I'm using a SUM() instead of A1.

=INT(SUM(G7:G36))+ INT((SUM(G7:G36)-INT(SUM(G7:G36)))/0.6)+ MOD((SUM(G7:G36)-INT(SUM(G7:G36))),0.6)

Comment: It doesn't work with sum. You add numbers not hours so 5.30 + 2.30 = 7.60 not 8.

Comment: In other words the sum is wrong not the conversion.

Comment: Can you help me resolve this and make it work with sum?

Comment: @NishitVaghela my answer is still the solution for what you asked above. I don't see the reason you unmarked it.